# What parts of .NET aren't available in Monotouch for IPhone dev?

Tags: .net, iphone, mobile, xamarin.ios, mobile-website

What are some key bindings that aren't included?

Comment: For starters, I imagine that it is .NET features, not C# features, that are missing

Comment: I've also found this site helpful. http://pristinecoder.com/Blog/post/monotouch-libraries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the complete list of limitations in MonoTouch at [Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations).

A short list of .NET features not available in MonoTouch:

- The Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR)
- Generic Virtual Methods
- P/Invokes in Generic Types
- Value types as Dictionary Keys
- System.Reflection.Emit
- System.Runtime.Remoting

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link of the assemblies that it ships with: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/assemblies

Here is a summary of the .Net framework assemblies:

> **mscorlib.dll**
> *Silverlight, plus several .NET 4.0 types*
>
> **System.dll**
> *Silverlight, plus types from the following namespaces:*
> System.Collections.Specialized
> System.ComponentModel
> System.ComponentModel.Design
> System.Diagnostics
> System.IO.Compression
> System.Net
> System.Net.Cache
> System.Net.Mail
> System.Net.Mime
> System.Net.NetworkInformation
> System.Net.Security
> System.Net.Sockets
> System.Security.Authentication
> System.Security.Cryptography
> System.Timers
>
> **System.Core.dll
>
> System.Data.dll
>
> System.Data.Services.Client.dll
>
> System.Json.dll
>
> System.Numerics.dll
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
>
> System.Transactions.dll
>
> System.Web.Services
>
> System.Xml.dll
>
> System.Xml.Linq.dll**

Answer (score 1):

One thing to also mention is you cannot reference .NET assemblies that haven't been built/compiled using the .NET MonoTouch configuration.

So if you have a favourite .NET 2.0 library you will need to re-import the source into a new MonoTouch project, compile it, and then reference it. There may be an easier way of doing this by editing the `.csproj` file but I haven't found it.