# MonoTouch Migration Analyser

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Is there any migration analysers available for MonoTouch ?

I have seen one for Mono, but not for MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, there is none at the moment.

**Long answer**

The situation is a bit different from Mono. In general you test a **complete** and **compiled** (against a specific version of the framework) .NET application with [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), to get a report of what pieces are missing (or incomplete) in Mono that could affect the execution of your application on other platforms (e.g. OSX and Linux).

Testing a **complete** applications for MonoTouch would reports tons of issues - since the UI toolkit is totally different. E.g. anything about System.Windows.Forms, WPF... would **always** missing.

However if your assemblies are already split into (something like) an MVC design it *would* be possible to test some (the non-UI parts) of them against definitions based on the MonoTouch base class library.

Finally if someone has an immediate need (or looking for a nice project) MoMA is available as open source and the evaluation versions of MonoTouch contains all the assemblies needed to build the definitions files. A bit of extra filtering could make this into a very nice tool.

**Alternative**

You can see a [list of the assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668647/220643) that are part of MonoTouch and some platform [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668642/220643) (compared to .NET) you should be aware.