# Can I LINQ a JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, linq-to-json

This is the JSON I get from a request on .NET:

```
{
  "id": "110355660738", 
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/1027085_12033235063_5234302342947_n.jpg", 
      "is_silhouette": false
    }
  }
}
```

and I'd like to catch the field "url", using (maybe?) LINQ. I do many request as this, that differents a bit. So I won't to create a C# Class and deserialize it every time.

Is it a way to extract a single field? Thank you!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No need for Linq, just use `dynamic` (using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/))

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine((string)obj.picture.data.url);
```

Linq version would not be much readable

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var url = (string)jObj.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "url")
                    .First()
                    .Value;
```

Documentation: **[LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)**

Comment: Just a side note: `.Where(p => p.Name == "url").First()` can just be replaced by `.First(p => p.Name == "url")`.

Comment: When you use `dynamic`, no need to use the cast in `(string)obj.picture.data.url`. You can simply write `Console.WriteLine(obj.picture.data.url);` and the correct overload will be invoked at runtime!

Comment: @Nawaz I know, it is only to show that `obj.picture.data.url` is in fact a `JToken` not string.

Comment: I think you meant `).Value<string>()` or something like that cause your code won't work.

Comment: The use of dynamic should not be recommended if you want your code to be reusable on mobile platforms: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1668642

Comment: if you use SimpleJSON you can just do myJSONNode.Linq.Where(x=>x.Value["name"] == "me").FirstOrDefault().Value

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend LINQ. I would recommend a JSON library such as newtonsoft.json.

So you can do this:

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];

// Apple
JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];
string smallest = (string)sizes[0];

// Small
```

Note:- this code has been copied from the samples present on the project site
http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: Where is the LINQ in your example?

Comment: @MichaëlHompus Why would anyone need LINQ here?

Comment: Well, look at the title of the question? :)

Comment: Just a side-note: JObject, JArray and JToken are in the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In a bind you could always deserialize the JSON and serialize it to XML, and load the XML in a XDocument. Then you can use the classic Linq to XML. When you are done take the XML, deserialize it, and serialize it back to JSON to JSON. We used this technique to add JSON support to an application that was originally built for XML, it allowed near-zero modifications to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily query with LINQ like this

considering this JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "two"
        }
    ]
}
```

let's put it in a variable called `json` like this,

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse("{'items':[{'id':'10','name':'one'},{'id':'12','name':'two'}]}");
```

you  can select all ids from the items where name is `"one"` using the following LINQ query

```
var Ids =
    from item in json["items"]
    where (string)item["name"] == "one"
    select item["id"];
```

Then, you will have the result in an IEnumerable list