# How to generate MSSQL Hierarchy ID for each element for a tree object

Tags: c#, sql-server, tree, hierarchical-data

I've a requirement like dragable tree in my project.
I've successfully converted mssql resultset to json.

But the end user is again dragging and dropping and totally changed the tree structure.
Now I have the below json from the client.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "1. dragon-breath",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "1. dragon-breath.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 100,
            "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2",
            "items": [
              {
                "id": 1000,
                "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2.3",
                "items": [],
                "pos": 3
              }
            ],
            "pos": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 101,
            "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2",
            "items": [],
            "pos": 2
          }
        ],
        "pos": 1
      }
    ],
    "pos": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1020,
        "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2.1",
        "items": [],
        "pos": 1
      }
    ],
    "pos": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1021,
    "title": "1. dragon-breath.1.2.1",
    "items": [],
    "pos": 1
  }
]
```

From the above json "pos" property is for MSSQL Hierarchyid value.

I am trying to regenerate the hierarchy id of each element, when this json posted back from the client.

I am requesting you people to help me. (spend 2 days no luck)

Comment: Why do you need the `pos` attribute, it seems your `id` values give you the hierarchy?

Comment: id is generating random only @Tony, No depth limit..@Malk
Thanks.

I am using http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/ for UI

Comment: You say you've "..successfully converted mssql resultset to json" so please show the table structure (with the same sample data) you are using to store the tree in the database; without it it's hard to say what the best approach would be.

Comment: I've used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945216/converting-flattened-hierarchical-data-from-sql-server-into-a-structured-json-ob?answertab=active to convert mssql to c# json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link you posted to the other SO question, and then a link from a comment, I see you are using the MSSQL `hierarchyid` data type (hint: it might have helped if you been a bit clearer about that in your question ;)

From the online help I see there is a [Parse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677201.aspx) function, which takes a string.

So you need to traverse your JSON tree structure, building strings for each element in the form `/1/1/3/` for example, and pass those back to your database along with the associated node `id`.

Comment: Thanks Tony, i hope this solution should work.Could please give me any hint or sample code to generate the hierarchy id by traverse the linq

Comment: @sathishkumar - Unfortunately LINQ is not my strong point, but a quick search turned up the [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library which might help you parse the hierarchy in to C# objects (if that's easier for you to code). The answer to the SO question [Can I LINQ a JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758361/can-i-linq-a-json) recommends the same library.