# how to filter json data using ling to json query

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-json

I'm new to json. I have to filter json data using linq to json query in C#.I have to retrieve multiple values from the below sample json data:

```
{
    "parts": [
    {

      "attributes": {
        "Motherboard": "Gigabyte GA-H81M-S2H",
        "Max RAM": "16GB",
        "Form Factor": "Micro ATX",
        "RAM Slots": 2,
        "Socket / CPU": "LGA1150"
      },
      "type": "Motherboard",
      "name": "Gigabyte GA-H81M-S2H",
      "slug": "gigabyte-motherboard-gah81ms2h"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
        "Motherboard": "MSI H55-G43",
        "Max RAM": "16GB",
        "Form Factor": "ATX",
        "RAM Slots": 4,
        "Socket / CPU": "LGA1156"
      },
      "type": "Motherboard",
      "name": "MSI H55-G43",
      "slug": "msi-motherboard-h55g43"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://pcpartpicker.com/part/asus-motherboard-rampageivblackedition",
      "attributes": {
        "Motherboard": "Asus Rampage IV Black Edition",
        "Max RAM": "128GB",
        "Form Factor": "EATX",
        "RAM Slots": 8,
        "Socket / CPU": "LGA2011"
      },
      "type": "Motherboard",
      "name": "Asus Rampage IV Black Edition",
      "slug": "asus-motherboard-rampageivblackedition"
    }
 ],

}
```

please help me with query how to select multiple (key,values) using where clause.I have to select name,slug,form factor,motherboard using where clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I LINQ a JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758361/can-i-linq-a-json)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create classes with respect to your `JSON` content structure. [This free online tool](http://json2csharp.com/) can help you creating C# classes from JSON data easily. Then you will need to parse this JSON to an object of C# class.

After that, you can perform `LINQ` operations on this `object`, filter them and parse back to the `JSON` if required.

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for all serialization and de-serialization operations.

Study [this great article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) for writing LINQ queries.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions,but what i want to know is how to write linq query to retrieve those values.

Comment: First create classes as I've suggested and then try writing `LINQ` by yourself. I will help then with specific queries (if any).