# Parsing ony few fields of JSON

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, api, parsing

I'm new to JSON so I hope you can help me.
I did this:

```
var myfields = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s);
```

this is the link for the JSON: [link](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:lantus)
As you can see I have many fields, each field is shown few times.
Now I have access only to the first one.
for example:

```
 final = myfields.results.First().warnings[0];
```

This String contains the first warnings field.
I tried to put instead of 0 - 1 but I get an error.

How can I get the others?

Thanks

Comment: What's you tried ? Give we a sample of the json that you received and the expected output.

Comment: Please show your work. We can't help you solve your problem without seeing what issue you're having.

Comment: A [mcve] demonstrating the problem would be required for us to help.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: In the absence of a [mcve], you could install [tag:json.net] then use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).  See [Can I LINQ a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758361/can-i-linq-a-json).  Or use `SelectToken` as explained in [Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645501).

Answer (score 4):

Create class with only fields you need and then deserialize json

```
public class YourTwoField
{
    [JsonProperty("field1")]
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field2")]
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}

var myfields = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourTwoField>(yourJsonString);
// use values
myfields.FieldOne
```

**Update on comments:**

Your problem was that You didn't provide enough information at the beginning.
Fields you required is in the bottom level of JSON hierarchy.

1. Copy your json result to the clipboard
2. In Visual Studio open empty file
3. Then `Edit` -> `Paste Special` -> Paste JSON as Classes

Now get all JSON schema as classes where I think will be generated some `RootObject`, then

```
var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);

//Then your can brows to the values you want
root.results.First().openfda.generic_name
root.results.First().openfda.brand_name
```

Or loop all results

```
foreach(var result in root.results)
{
    result.openfda.generic_name;
    result.openfda.brand_name;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You everyone. this is for example the api results: [link](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:humalog&limit=15), I had issues with Deserialize the JSON.

Comment: What kind of issues? and add your api result to the question

Comment: Hi, I added a link in the comment before. I had problems with parsing selected fields, Now I see your tip and I'll try to use it.

Comment: Hi this is what I did, [link](http://txt.do/d5fvg), this is the class [link](http://txt.do/d5fvu) and still It doesnt working, I'm getting thie error: An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll. I hope you can help me

Comment: @RonF, Put all this information to the question - so you will get more help. And provide more information about exception you got - maybe Inner Exception message

Comment: Thank You! I'm sorry but I dont understand what to do. I started a new thread more arranged. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561970/deserialize-json-object-error) Can you help me there?

Comment: There is the same answer as I have here

Comment: Hi I'm facing now a new problem, I have access only to the first brand_name. How can I access the others?