# Deserialize JSon Object error

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

Hi I need your help for Deserialize Json Object. This is The code I wrote,

```
String s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop/json1.json");
var myfields = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourTwoField>(s);
Console.WriteLine(myfields.FieldOne);
```

and this is the class for the JSON OBJECT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;


public class YourTwoField
{
    [JsonProperty("brand_name")]
    public List<string> FieldOne { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("generic_name")]
    public List<string> FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

and still It doesnt working, I'm getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

This is the JSON results: [link](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:humalog&limit=15)

Thanks

Comment: Why is there a space in your file string?

Comment: I deleted it, Still doesnt working

Comment: What does your JSON file look like?

Comment: [link](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:humalog&limit=15)

Answer (score 1):

The json contains a **list** of results that contain a `openfda` property. As wel as a `openfda` that can contain more then one `brand_name` and `generic_name`.

Because you are asking to only get these two properties, my example is based on only those two.

### Strongly typed

Classes:

```
public class Openfda
{     
    [JsonProperty("generic_name")]
    public List<string> GenericName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("brand_name")]
    public List<string> BrandName { get; set; }     
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("openfda")]
    public Openfda Openfda { get; set; }   
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing:

```
var myfields = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

Console.WriteLine(myfields.Results[0].Openfda.BrandName[0]);
Console.WriteLine(myfields.Results[0].Openfda.GenericName[0]);
```

---

### Dynamic

The `dynamic` way (without strong typed properties):

```
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Console.WriteLine(obj.results[0].openfda.brand_name[0]);
Console.WriteLine(obj.results[0].openfda.generic_name[0]);
```

Comment: @RonF your welcome, if one of the answers helped you and solved your question, then you should mark that answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data does not fit to your class structure. You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to get help for this task. With the provided sample data the data classes look like

```
...
var myfields = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);
...
```

**Generated Classes**

```
public class Results
{
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public string disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string terms { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string last_updated { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
}

public class Openfda
{
    public List<string> product_ndc { get; set; }
    public List<string> nui { get; set; }
    public List<string> package_ndc { get; set; }
    public List<string> generic_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_set_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> pharm_class_cs { get; set; }
    public List<string> brand_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> original_packager_product_ndc { get; set; }
    public List<string> manufacturer_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> unii { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> substance_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> product_type { get; set; }
    public List<string> route { get; set; }
    public List<string> application_number { get; set; }
    public List<string> pharm_class_epc { get; set; }
    public List<bool?> is_original_packager { get; set; }
    public List<string> upc { get; set; }
    public List<string> rxcui { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string effective_time { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_unclassified_section_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> inactive_ingredient { get; set; }
    public List<string> instructions_for_use { get; set; }
    public List<string> purpose { get; set; }
    public List<string> keep_out_of_reach_of_children { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_patient_package_insert { get; set; }
    public List<string> warnings { get; set; }
    public List<string> description { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_product_data_elements { get; set; }
    public Openfda openfda { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public List<string> dosage_and_administration { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_unclassified_section { get; set; }
    public List<string> storage_and_handling { get; set; }
    public List<string> package_label_principal_display_panel { get; set; }
    public List<string> indications_and_usage { get; set; }
    public string set_id { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> spl_patient_package_insert_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> active_ingredient { get; set; }
    public List<string> drug_interactions { get; set; }
    public List<string> geriatric_use { get; set; }
    public List<string> precautions { get; set; }
    public List<string> pharmacodynamics { get; set; }
    public List<string> general_precautions { get; set; }
    public List<string> pharmacokinetics { get; set; }
    public List<string> teratogenic_effects { get; set; }
    public List<string> dosage_and_administration_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> pediatric_use { get; set; }
    public List<string> contraindications { get; set; }
    public List<string> storage_and_handling_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> pregnancy { get; set; }
    public List<string> nursing_mothers { get; set; }
    public List<string> adverse_reactions { get; set; }
    public List<string> how_supplied_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> laboratory_tests { get; set; }
    public List<string> how_supplied { get; set; }
    public List<string> information_for_patients { get; set; }
    public List<string> clinical_pharmacology { get; set; }
    public List<string> carcinogenesis_and_mutagenesis_and_impairment_of_fertility { get; set; }
    public List<string> overdosage { get; set; }
    public List<string> recent_major_changes { get; set; }
    public List<string> nonclinical_toxicology { get; set; }
    public List<string> dosage_forms_and_strengths { get; set; }
    public List<string> mechanism_of_action { get; set; }
    public List<string> clinical_studies_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> adverse_reactions_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> warnings_and_cautions { get; set; }
    public List<string> recent_major_changes_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> animal_pharmacology_and_or_toxicology { get; set; }
    public List<string> use_in_specific_populations { get; set; }
    public List<string> clinical_studies { get; set; }
    public List<string> clinical_pharmacology_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> instructions_for_use_table { get; set; }
    public List<string> pharmacodynamics_table { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @robe I tried it but it also didnt work. I want only spefcific fields and not all of them