# How to get list of objects from list of jobjects based on key exists or not?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

This is my code:-

```
List<JObject> students =[{"id":"101","name":"one","parent_id":"1"},{"id":"102","name":"two","parent_id":"2"},{"id":"103","name":"three"},{"id":"104","name":"four"}];
```

I tried the following code using Linq but not working

```
List<JObject> newStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id").ToString() == null).ToList();


List<JObject> existedStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id").ToString() != null).ToList();
```

In the above list contains 4 objects , first two objects contains `parent_id` key next two objects doesn't contain. How to `parent_id` key existed and not existed list in c#.

Comment: Can you try with List<dynamic> rather a List<JObject>? if you are getting the JSON from some api, just deserialize the JSON as a List<dynamic>

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758361/can-i-linq-a-json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Property.htm), `JObject.Property` returns `null` if the property does not exist

Thus

```
x.Property("parent_id").ToString()
```

will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `parent_id` does not exist.

To check whether a property exists do not use the `ToString()`, just compare `Property` to `null`:

```
List<JObject> newStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id") == null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do as follows

```
List<JObject> newStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id").Value<string>() == null).ToList();


List<JObject> existedStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id").Value<string>() != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the property does not exist, the `Property` method returns null, [according to the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Property.htm).

So do not call `.ToString()`, otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`. Instead:

```
List<JObject> newStudents = students.Where(x => x.Property("parent_id") == null).ToList();
```